# Dokan vendor add shortcode to each vendor

Tags: wordpress, dokan

I have created e-commerce site with dokan.
I want to add each vendor their own livechat.
I have configured everything and just need to add short code to each vendor, but Dokan don't create new pages for vendors and I can't figure out how to do it.
I sniffed around in Dokan manuals, but can't find this specific field/place to enter shortcode

Can anybody point me into right directon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dokan_store_profile_frame_after` hook which runs only in the store page to add your shortcode. This hook is run just after the store profile. If you want to exclude certain stores, you can use the $store_user and $store_info to filter out the stores. You can add the following code the `functions.php` file of the theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    $store_user   = dokan()->vendor->get( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
    $store_info   = $store_user->get_shop_info();

    if ( dokan_is_store_page() ) {
       echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="64" title="Contact form 1"]');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't follow under where I can add this code section
I See that I have under "dokan" following: products-widget.php, store-header.php, store-lists-loop.php, store.php

Comment: @N2hvits You can add the following code in the functions.php file of the theme.

Comment: Only problem with changing with this code is it messing up whole layout and shortcode isn't presented

Comment: @N2hvits I have updated the code again. Now it appends at the shortcode at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @N2hvits yeah it appends the shortcode at the bottom of the store page.

Comment: How can I add it to specific store not for all?
Like electronics one shortcode for makeup another shortcode

Comment: @N2hvits I have updates the code with the store user and store info. You can use these to filter out the vendors.

Comment: unfortunately still messing up whole layout and didn't pop out chat window either

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TalkJs. As per their website they support Dokan. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/talkjs/
https://talkjs.com/knowledge-base/article/does-talkjs-work-with-support/

Comment: Sry but this doesen't have videocall function.
That's why I need to add shortcode to each dokan vendor
I am using 3CX software